# OOP and Threading subclass

Tags: python, oop, python-multithreading

When we subclass the threading class, is calling the original threading`__init__` method within our new class's`__init__` method, essentially just wiping the slate clean?
Or are we inheriting the  original `__init__`method's attributes?

This is how the original `__init__`looks for  the threading class (abridged form)

```
 def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None):



        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = {}
        self._target = target
        self._name = str(name or _newname())
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs
```

So now when I create a subclass and def my **int** as such:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, number):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.number = number
        print(number)
```

Does this mean I am overwriting  the original threading classes
**init** attributes such as

```
group=None, target=None, name=None,
    args=(), kwargs=None, *, daemon=None
```

and thus only have access to the one attribute number that I created within my
new **init** method.

If so, is there a way to still have access to the original **init** attributes
and just add on top of those attributes when I create my new
subclass?

Comment: No, you will have access to any attributes assigned to `self` in any method you call, including the base-class `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current subclass can only instantiate a `Thread` with it's default arguments.

To avoid having to rewrite the arguments, a form like this can be used:

```
def __init__(self,
             subclass_positional_arg, *args,
             subclass_kw_arg=None, other_arg=None, **kwargs):
    super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Do stuff with `subclass_positional_arg`, 
    # `subclass_kw_arg` and `other_arg`
```

And you could instantiate it like this:

```
MyThread(positional, subclass_kw_arg=value)
MyThread(positional)
```

In your specific situation, you could do one of these two things:

```
def __init__(self, *args, number, **kwargs):
    super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.number = number

MyThread(number=<number>)  # You could also give a default value
```

```
def __init__(self, number, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.number = number

MyThread(<number>)
# or
MyThread(number=<number>)
# Though you could no longer give a default value
```

---

In Python 2, keyword-only arguments are not allowed. You achieve a similar effect by popping from `**kwargs`

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Use `kwargs.pop('number', <default value>)` to be optional
    number = kwargs.pop('number')
    super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.number = number
```

Comment: Thank you =) . Going to test out your suggestions and see if I have any other questions.